# Need help in how to map ZIP codes data by year

Tags: cartography, zip-codes

I'd like to build a graphic showing where city employees live, based on their date of hire. I have a list showing the hire date and the ZIP code for each employee. There are about 4,000 employees.

I can't figure out how to do that, despite it being very easy to explain!

Comment: How do you intend to display zip codes that have multiple employees from multiple years?  It will be easier to either 1) show individual employees as points, with icons/colors by year or 2) number of employees per zip code, but not combine the two methods.

Comment: That's what I was asking for help on - I can't figure out how to combine the two data points.

Comment: When you say "build a graphic" do you mean something like "draw something in Photoshop" or "make a map using ArcGIS" or what?

Comment: I work for a news organization, so I'd need to be able to build a factually accurate map which could then be rendered by an artist into something suitable for publication.

Comment: The user has not visited the site since the question was originally asked nearly a year ago. 